# Text in my Horizontal list view is not being displayed

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, android-listview, horizontallistview

I am building a horizontal list view where I want to display products with a caption describing the product. Each element in the list view must display an image from the url provided and have caption text beneath it. So far it works fine and displays the images but the text will not appear. I am not receiving any log errors and have used different emulators in case that was the issue with no success.

Any help and explanation would be greatly appreciated.

```
class HorizontalList extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(
      height: 80.0,
      child: ListView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        children: <Widget>[
          Category(
            image_location: 'images/cats/accessories.png',
            image_caption: 'accessories',
          ),
      Category(
        image_location: 'images/cats/dress.png',
        image_caption: 'dress',
      ),

      Category(
        image_location: 'images/cats/formal.png',
        image_caption: 'formal',
      ),

      Category(
        image_location: 'images/cats/informal.png',
        image_caption: 'informal',
      ),

      Category(
        image_location: 'images/cats/tshirt.png',
        image_caption: 'tshirt',
      ),

      Category(
        image_location: 'images/cats/jeans.png',
        image_caption: 'jeans',
      ),

      Category(
        image_location: 'images/cats/shoe.png',
        image_caption: 'shoe',
      ),

        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}


class Category extends StatelessWidget {
  final String image_location;
  final String image_caption;

  Category({
    this.image_location,
    this.image_caption
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
      child: InkWell(onTap: () {},
        child: Container(
          width: 100.0,
          child: ListTile(
            title: Image.asset(image_location,
              width: 100.0,
              height: 80.0,),
            subtitle: Container(
              alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                child: Text(image_caption),
            )
          ),
        ),
      ),);
  }
}
```

Comment: I recommend replacing your `ListView` with a `RecylcerView` for major performance improvements, especially when you are displaying pictures. See the documentation here https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview

Comment: I am using Flutter

Comment: Try these:
1. Changing the colour of the text in the Text() widget
2. Place the text widget directly in the subtitle parameter in other words remove the 
    container wrapping it.
3. Print the caption in the log to see if it has some data